# How to perform Upsert in solr

Tags: java, apache, indexing, solr, upsert

I have a collection in solr populated from a external data source.Data in external data source may contain new data or  old data may get updated everyday.I need to perform a upsert operation based on this external data stream.If new document is there, insert it in solr collection,if old document has been modified update the corresponding fields and if no field has been changed for that document ,then do nothing.
How to perform it using org.apache.solr jar

Comment: This is the default behavior for updates sent to Solr - any duplicate id will overwrite the old id, while a new document is inserted if the id doesn't already exist. What is wrong with the current behavior you're seeing?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for clarifying this.Now i am clear how unique id helps in performing upsert operation in solr.. :)